# Product / Co-product in category of sets and relations (Rel)

Tags: category-theory

What is the co-product and product in category of sets and relations.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the product and coproduct of a family of sets $X_i$ are given as the disjoint union $\coprod X_i$ of sets together with the relations
$$\left\{(a, a) \in \left(\coprod X_i\right) \times X_j \ \middle| \ \forall a \in X_j\right\}$$
and
$$\left\{(a, a) \in X_j \times \left(\coprod X_i\right) \ \middle| \ \forall a \in X_j\right\}.$$

Comment: What is $X_j$? Is $j$ in the index set?